# Clicking on a Demonstration doesn't open CDF Player 11.0.1.0 for Mac OS X

Tags: cdfplayer, version-11

I have

> Mathematica 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)

When I click an item on the Demonstrations site, it says

> "Iteract Now! Get the free Wolfram CDF Player >>".

So I downloaded and installed the latest CDF Player. Now the (About CDF Player) window says I have

> CDF Player version 11.0.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit kernel).

Now, if I click on a Demonstration it still says,

> "Interact Now! Get the free Wolfram CDF Player >>".

Although I can download a CDF from the demonstrations site, then open it with the CDF Player and it works fine. So how can I make it so CDF Player is used as soon as I click on a demonstration?

**EDIT**
My computer is a Macbok Pro with Retna display & quad core Intel i7 processor
My browser is Safari version 10.0.1 (10602.2.14.0.7)

Comment: Are you using a [supported browser](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/20057)?  The browser plugin only works in 32 bit browsers that support NPAPI.  This does not include things like Chrome.

Comment: @KAI, I edited my question to include details on my browser and hardware.